# Visual Studio Security popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

When I run my web application I get a Windows Security popup asking me to enter my credentials.

This is preventing me from running my program properly, how can I disable this option?

[image: popup screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like your web application is running with Windows [authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.71).aspx).

To use Forms authentication, modify your web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```